# What parameters are considered for deciding a movie's "close date"

Tags: production, box-office

On [this page](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=split2017.htm) on boxofficemojo, There is a mention of a **close date**.

[image: screenshot]

I understand that this date is the cutoff date for counting box office sales but what parameters are considered for deciding this date? does it have anything do with attendance?

Comment: Looks like May 4th to me =P

Comment: @Steve-O May the 4th b with u

Comment: Are you asking what the decision parameters are for considering a movie closed?

Comment: I am asking very clearly.

Comment: As far as i can tell, the *close date* isn't exactly related to stopping record ing box office takings...it refers to the date that the movie stops being on general release in movie theatres. **It's almost the same** thing though and it's generally around 90 /100 days after which the movie might be available for download or on DVD etc.